# How to fix Router issue in React Js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have written below code and my issue that on submit I am getting couple of error:

> mapDispatchToProps() in Connect(ProductPage) must return a plain
>   object. Instead received undefined.
>
> Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.submitProductRequest is not a function

I m not getting what mistake I have done in the code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { submitProductRequest } from './actions';
import { ProductDetailsActions, ProductDetailsType } from './types';
import Container from '../../components/Container';

interface DispatchProps {
  push: (path: string) => void;
}

interface Props extends DispatchProps, ProductDetailsActions {
  currencies: string;
  currencyCode: string;
  finalAmount: number;
  newFinal: number;
  exchangeRate: number;
}

interface State extends ProductDetailsType {}

class ProductPage extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  public state: State = {
    amount: null,
  };


  private handleSubmit = () => {
    const { currencyCode, amount, exchangeRate } = this.state;

    this.props.submitProductRequest({         
      amount,
    });
    this.props.push('/fulfillment');
  };

  render() {
    const { amount, exchangeRate } = this.state;

    return (


          <input
            id="quantity"
            name="quantity"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.amount || ''}
            onChange={this.qtyChange}
          />

        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="button">
          Submit
        </button>

    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
   return {
     p: state.personalDetails,
   };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) =>{
  push: push;
  bindActionCreators({ submitProductRequest }, dispatch);
}

const withConnect = connect<DispatchProps>(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps,
);

export default withConnect(ProductPage);
```

I want to use redux action to pass data input value to another component. Also, we have used React Boilerplate framework

Comment: get "Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to resolve this issue by returning values in MapStatestoProps like Clarity suggested.

Appreciated your help.

Answer (score -1):

Your mapDispatchToProps isn't returning anything.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your `mapDispatchToProps` function.
You need to return an object..

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  push: push,
  actions: bindActionCreators({ submitProductRequest }, dispatch);
})
```

and when you use that action in component use like this....

```
this.props.actions.submitProductRequest()
```

in your case...

```
private handleSubmit = () => {    
    const { currencyCode, amount, exchangeRate } = this.state;
    this.props.actions.submitProductRequest({
        amount,
    });
    this.props.push('/fulfillment');
};
```